# shutdown from gnome menu doesn't ask password

Tags: password, shutdown

I want to prevent my roommates to shutdown my computer without needing my password from the gnome menu at the top. i would like to keed dbus permissions since i am using that commands with alias. everybody is asking to how not to require a password but there is little and obsolete knowledge about this issue on the internet. thank you in advance
i am using 14.04

Comment: What happens if you use the key combination CTRL-ALT-L ?

Comment: it locks my desktop

Comment: But the shutdown option is still there and doesn't require a password. Correct?

Comment: yes exactly. and i want it to ask for password or i want them to do nothing at all

Comment: Lets go with nothing at all....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in dconf editor. You can install this with `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` See below for the adjustments to make. You can also choose to suppress the restart menu item (among others)

[image: dconfsuppressshutdown]

Suppressing the menu item will remove the option from the menu in the upper right corner of the screen. (After a reboot). Of course the option won't exist for you either but you can always shutdown by opening a terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and issuing the command `sudo shutdown -h now` or restart with `sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: Your very welcome! If after a period of time this answer is still the best, feel free to upvote it by clicking the up arrow next to the zero.

Comment: i tried to upvote but it says that i need 15 reputation to upvote :s until that time i will keep this post in my mind. i am very happy with the result :)